# Using mdTooltip in Angular-CLI Project

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

I am trying to implement a tooltip using Angular 2's material in an Angular-CLI project. The documentation is a little unclear on exactly what's needed. All I need is a standard tooltip popup to show up.

In my component HTML I have this:

```
<button md-raised-button mdTooltip="This is a tooltip!" mdTooltipPosition="below">Button</button>
```

In my app.module I have this (edited for brevity):

```
import { MaterialModule } from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        MaterialModule.forRoot(),
    ]
```

I also have material and hammer.js listed in my package.json (as hammer.js is apparently a dependency for the mdTooltip). Here's my package.json:

```
    {
  "name": "abc",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ng serve",
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update",
    "e2e": "protractor"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.2.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.2.3",
    "@angular/core": "2.2.3",
    "@angular/forms": "2.2.3",
    "@angular/http": "2.2.3",
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.2.3",
    "@angular/router": "3.2.3",
    "@types/socket.io": "^1.4.27",
    "@types/socket.io-client": "^1.4.29",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.1.15",
    "angular2-chartjs": "^0.1.6",
    "chart.js": "^2.4.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "ng2-charts": "^1.4.1",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "socket.io": "^1.7.2",
    "socket.io-client": "^1.7.2",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.23"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.2.3",
    "@types/hammerjs": "^2.0.34",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.42",
    "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.22-1",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0-beta.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
    "karma": "1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.2.1",
    "protractor": "4.0.9",
    "ts-node": "1.2.1",
    "typescript": "~2.0.3",
    "typings": "^1.3.2",
    "webdriver-manager": "10.2.5"
  }
}
```

I'm unclear on what I need to also import into the component.ts file and what else, if anything, is needed to get this working. Here's what I have for the component file now:

```
import { MaterialModule } from '@angular/material';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-room',
  templateUrl: './room.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./room.component.less']
})
export class RoomComponent implements OnInit {

  otherImg = 'app/img/avatar.svg';

  others = [
    { id: 1, name: 'John Smith' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Javier Sanchez' }
  ];

  chat(other) {
    console.log('Room chat function initiated...');
  }

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Right now I see a button in my component view. But no tooltip shows up when I hover over or click on the button. It shows the other material design elements (raised button styling, etc), but no tooltip.

My polyfills.ts file looks like this:

```
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';
import 'core-js/es6/reflect';

import 'core-js/es7/reflect';
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';
```

Comment: your `polyfills.ts` file ?

Comment: Just added it above.

Comment: Try to add `import 'hammerjs/hammer';`

Comment: Tried that. Still no go.

Answer (score 2):

Use `md-tooltip` instead of `mdTooltip`:

`<button md-raised-button md-tooltip="This is a tooltip!" mdTooltipPosition="below">Button</button>`